# Odoo - How to compare stored dates before validation

Tags: postgresql, odoo, odoo-8

I am working on a meeting room reservation module on Odoo
I am trying to compare the date that I am about the insert with the dates that I have in the database.
i tried the search(),  the browse() functions i also tried to iterate on the recordset but it always points on the record that i am about to insert.
i was thinking about doint it through an SQL query but i can't find the table's name where the data is stored.

Here is the class definition:

```
class Reservation(models.Model):
    _name = 'module001.reservation'

    name = fields.Char(String="Reservation Number", required=True)
    start_date = fields.Datetime(default=fields.Date.today)
    room_number = fields.Many2one('module001.room', ondelete='cascade', string="Room", required=True)
    reserved_for = fields.Many2one('res.partner', string="Reserved for ")
    end_date = fields.Datetime(string="End Date", store=True)
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you want to compare the start_date and end_date fields in your case  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it done this way so i can compare every date of the records that i have already with the current record that i am about to insert

```
@api.multi
@api.constrains('start_date', 'end_date', 'name')
def _check_date(self):
    envir = self.env['tt.reservation'].search([('id', '!=', self.id)])
    for record in envir:
        start_self = datetime.datetime.strptime(self.start_date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        end_self = datetime.datetime.strptime(self.end_date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        start_rec = datetime.datetime.strptime(record.start_date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        end_rec = datetime.datetime.strptime(record.end_date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

#verification de la diponibilite de la salle
        if self.room_id == record.room_id:
            if start_self.date() == start_rec.date() and start_self.date() == end_rec.date():
                if ((start_self.time() > start_rec.time() and start_self.time() < end_rec.time()) or (end_self.time() > start_rec.time() and end_self.time() < end_rec.time()) or (start_self.time() <= start_rec.time() and end_self.time() >= end_rec.time())):
                    raise exceptions.ValidationError("Salle occupée")
```